# How to loop my ajax request n time sequentially with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I want to call ajax request 3 times sequentially (requests have same URL) as describe:
`Request 1 -> Done -> Request 2 -> Done -> Request 3 -> Done -> Do something`

In each callback functions, if have any conditions is correct, the loop will be end.
I can write simple script to do, like:

```
$.ajax().then(function () {
    if (condition) {}
    else {
        $.ajax().then(function () {
            if () else () {
                $.ajax().then(function () {
                    if () else ();
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

But if its not only 3 times (ex n times), it looks so so stupid.
How I make many requests using `Promise`?
Thanks a lots!

Comment: Have any better solutions?

Answer (score 3):

Using *vanilla promises*, a "recursive function" would work. Simply supply the number of times (plus one) on each recursive call.. the recursive function will itself return a new promise if there is additional work to be done.

```
var maxCalls = 3

function makeCall(timesCalled) {
   // we're done - don't return a chained promise
   if (timesCalled > maxCalls)
     return;

   return $.ajax().then(function () {
      // likewise - don't return chained promise
      // (it may make sense to move this up outside)
      if (condition)
         return;

      // return the next promise, or not if done
      return makeCall(timesCalled + 1);
   });
 }

var promiseResolvedAtEnd = makeCall(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Classic JavaScript problem.

You can look into "generators" with **yield** keyword.

It's a new feature in EcmaScript 6, made to make asynchronous calls look/feel synchronous.

That's exactly what avoids the "Ajax Christmas-tree" you've stumbled upon, without breaking asynchronous nature of your calls.

Now they *might* look a little convoluted at first. But once you get into it, it should become second nature. Imagine never having to deal with the recursive web of $.ajax events again.

Note: I myself don't fully understand them yet. But in my experiments so far I got the code you're seeing below. I think you have to call wrapper eventually by passing generator to it. If anyone else can shed more light on this, it would be appreciated.

Here is an example:

```
<script>

    // -- I: Basic Example

    function generator()
    {
        yield 0 + 1;
        yield 0 + 2;
        yield 0 + 3;
        yield "Hello";
        return "Done.";
    }

    var gen = generator();

    // Iterate through return values until done

    gen.next(); // 1
    gen.next(); // 2
    gen.next(); // 3
    gen.next(); // "Hello."
    gen.next(); // "Done."


    // -- II: Take this principle to a real-case scenario:

    window.onload = function() {

        // Generator - asynchronous code that looks synchronous
        function generator() {
            var tweets = yield $.getJSON("data/tweets.json");
            var friends = yield $.getJSON("data/friends.json");
            var followers = yield $.getJSON("data/followers.json");
        }

        // Wrap
        function wrapper(generator) {
            var gen = generator();

            // Handle
            function handle(yielded) {
                if (!yielded.done) {

                    // Then
                    yielded.value.then(function(data) {

                        // Next
                        return handle(gen.next(data));
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its so clearly. But I have deadline at this time, so that the way of @user2864740 is easier for coding. I will try to test your solutions as soon as possible. Thanks again!